# user=request.user - name 'request' is not defined

Tags: python, django

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
...
class FruitList(ListView):
    model = Fruit
    paginate_by = "2"
    queryset = Fruit.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    context_object_name = "myfruitlist"
    template_name = 'myfruit_list.html'
```

Error:

> name 'request' is not defined

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to access it this way:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return Fruit.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
```

You can read about this [here in docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#dynamic-filtering)

Comment: In this way I have`self` is not defined

Comment: Maybe try to get queryset, the way docs describe it (I edited my post with solution)